# How to get row number in OnDrawColumnCell event?

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-6, tdbgrid

This is how my drawing routine for TDBGrid component looks like. I am replacing values from database based on some rules:

```
void __fastcall TForm_Loadpoint_Details::DBGrid1DrawColumnCell(
  TObject *Sender, const TRect &Rect, int DataCol, TColumn *Column,
  TGridDrawState State)
{
    int row_index = ???;
    AnsiString text = GetCustomizedText(row_index, DataCol);
    DrawText(text);
}
```

However I don't know how to tell which row is currently being rendered? Without this knowledge i can't get data for displaying.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Index` or `FieldNo` property of the `Column->Field` object, or you can use an accessor class to access the protected `TDBGrid::DataLink` property and then use its `ActiveRecord` property.

Comment: First two options are giving contradicting results for me (Index=1,FieldNo=3) but third option (TDBGrid::DataLink->ActiveRecord) seems to be OK.